# Issues with handling Oauth2.0 to add a video to a YouTube playlist, adding videos continuously

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-api, google-oauth

I am writing code in Python to automatically add a video to a YouTube playlist. The code does successfully add a video to the the playlist, however I am prompted with a login-consent screen for each video that I add. For every video that I add the auth flow repeats. I would like to have to only do this once.

```
def insertPlaylistItem(playlistId, videoID):   
    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client_secret.json"

    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console() # Save these credentials
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.playlistItems().insert(
            part="snippet",
            body={
                "snippet": {
                    "playlistId": playlistId,
                    "position": 0,
                  "resourceId": {
                    "kind": "youtube#video",
                    "videoId": videoID
                }
                }
            }
        )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)
```

client_secret.json is of this form:

```
{
    "installed":{
        "client_id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id":"XXXXXX",
        "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "redirect_uris":[
            "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
            "http://localhost"
            ]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to store these credentials provided by the auth flow so that they could be used later? I have read through https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert where I get it to work for javascript, but I just can't quite figure out the Python way. Am I incorrectly understanding the Oauth2.0 process?

With javascript I was able to get a token.json in the form:

```
{
    "access_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "refresh_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "expiry_date":1564674820338
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I ended up using the oauth2client module for python. I also had to use that module's flow rather that Google's flow due to the oauth2.json file being stored differently. Using Google's flow I continuously received: KeyError: '_module'.

The solution is:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run_flow

def insertPlaylistItem(playlistId, videoID):
    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client_secret.json"

    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(client_secrets_file, scopes)
    storage = Storage("oauth2.json")
    credentials = storage.get()
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = run_flow(flow, storage)
        storage.put(credentials)

    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.playlistItems().insert(
        part="snippet",
        body={
            "snippet": {
                "playlistId": playlistId,
                "position": 0,
                "resourceId": {
                    "kind": "youtube#video",
                    "videoId": videoID
                }
            }
        }
    )
    response = request.execute()
    print(response)
```